# OrderedDict contain list of DataFrame

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I don't understand why method1 is fine but not the second ...

**method 1**

```
import pandas as pd
import collections
d = collections.OrderedDict([('key', []), ('key2', [])])
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1], 'test': ['ok']})
d['key'].append(df)
d
OrderedDict([('key', [   id test
0   1   ok]), ('key2', [])])
```

**method 2**

```
l = ['key', 'key2']
dl = collections.OrderedDict(zip(l, [[]]*len(l)))
dl
OrderedDict([('key', []), ('key2', [])])
 dl['key'].append(df)
 dl
OrderedDict([('key', [   id test
0   1   ok]), ('key2', [   id test
0   1   ok])])
```

dl == d True

Comment: Maybe change `[[]]*len(l))` to `[[] for _ in l]`.

Comment: yes it's works thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue stems from creating empty lists like so: `[[]] * len(l)` what this is actually doing is copying the reference to the empty list multiple times. So what you end up with is a list of empty lists that all point to the same underlying object. When this happens, any change you make to the underlying list via inplace operations (such as `append`) will change the values inside of all references to that list.

The same type issue comes about when assigning variables to one another:

```
a = []
b = a

# `a` and `b` both point to the same underlying object.
b.append(1) # inplace operation changes underlying object

print(a, b)
[1], [1]
```

To circumvent your issue instead of using `[[]] * len(l)` you can use a generator expression or list comprehension to ensure a new empty list is created for each element in list `l`:

```
collections.OrderedDict(zip(l, ([] for _ in l))
```

using the generator expression `([] for _ in l)` creates a new empty list for every element in `l` instead of copying the reference to a single empty list. The easiest way to check this is to use the `id` function to check the underlying ids of the objects. Here we'll compare your original method to the new method:

```
# The ids come out the same, indicating that the objects are reference to the same underlying list
>>> [id(x) for x in [[]] * len(l)]
[2746221080960, 2746221080960] 

# The ids come out different, indicating that they point to different underlying lists
>>> [id(x) for x in ([] for _ in l)]
[2746259049600, 2746259213760]
```